# Setting up the Lagrangian for a pendulum with a circular weight

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

[image]A pendulum consists of a light inextensible rod $OA$, length $b$, freely pivoted at $O$, attached at $A$ to the rim of a uniform disc of radius $a$ and mass $m$. The disc is free to rotate about $A$. The system moves in a vertical plane containing $O$.

Can you help me to set Lagrangian?

I found that
$$\vec r_A=b\sin\theta\vec i+b\cos\theta\vec j$$
$$\dot{\vec r_A}=b\dot\theta\cos\theta\vec i-b\dot\theta\sin\theta\vec j$$

I am not sure if this is correct for point $G$ ($G$ is center of mass of a dics):
$$\vec r_G=(b\sin\theta+a\sin\phi)\vec i+(b\cos\theta+a\cos\phi)\vec j$$

This is all I've done for now. I would appreciate some help and hints for position vector of the point $G$ and forces acting here.

Comment: Where do $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ point? One has to guess for now...

Comment: $\vec i$ horizontaly to the right, $\vec j$ vertically downwards.

Comment: $\vec r_G$ looks correct since it's $\vec{OA}+\vec{AG}$. As for forces... is it in uniform gravitation field or completely free?

Comment: There is only gravitational force. I am only not sure how to use the fact that a disc rotates about $A$. Do I have to use rotating frame of reference? But no angular velocity is mentioned here.

Comment: You already have $\phi$, which accounts for rotation. This is just another coordinate in Lagrangian.

Comment: The force would be included as $-U(\vec r_G \cdot\vec j)$

Comment: What is $U$? How can I find kinetic energy of the center of a disc? Is there some standard formula for that or I have to apply theory of rigid body motion to find it? In the result for this problem there appears $\frac{3}{4}ma^2\dot\phi^2$ (it is approximated kinetic energy in the case of small oscillations) and I can't get it only using $T=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec {r_A}^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec {r_G}^2}$

Comment: I'd suggest you to repost this to Physics.SE, you'll be more likely to get a good answer there.

Comment: Ok, I will try there. Thank you!